# Inicializar variável com interface definida em TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Eu estou mexendo com Angular e dando manutenção em um código de versão mais antiga. Atualmente, quando precisamos definir os parâmetros de um objeto no TypeScript, utilizamos uma interface:

```
export interface RetornoEstatisticaAvaliacao {
  QuantidadeDetrator: number
  QuantidadeNeutro: number
  QuantidadePromotor: number
  PorcentagemDetrator: number
  PorcentagemNeutro: number
  PorcentagemPromotor: number
  ValorNps: number
}
```

Que antes era utilizado como classe para definição de tipo, logo antigamente conseguimos inicializar uma variável simplesmente instanciando essa classe:

```
estatisticaNps: RetornoEstatisticaAvaliacao = new RetornoEstatisticaAvaliacao();
```

Como ela atualmente não é mais uma **classe**, e sim uma **interface**, ele gera um erro de inicialização de variável:

> `RetornoEstatisticaAvaliacao` só faz referência a um tipo, mas está sendo usado como valor no momento.

Qual o jeito certo de inicializar essa variável com tipo definido?

Comment: Você não pode instanciar um tipo (como está fazendo agora). O que pode fazer é criar uma classe que implemente o tipo `RetornoEstatisticaAvaliacao`, de modo que seja possível instanciar essa classe que você tenha criado. Lembre-se que qualquer tipo é apagado em _runtime_ e, portanto, não é possível utilizá-los como se fizessem parte do código JavaScript emitido pelo `tsc`.

Comment: Então mas o problema é exatamente esse porque o código antigo fazia esse instância e hoje como eu alterei de classe para interface eu não posso instanciar mais. ai eu preciso inicializar a variável de alguma forma que não to sabendo como.

Comment: Basta criar uma classe que implementa a interface *RetornoEstatisticaAvaliacao*. [Veja como fazer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#implements-clauses)

Comment: Então a pergunta é: por que mudou de classe para interface? Se tem um bom motivo, então não tem jeito, precisa criar uma classe que a implementa. Se não tem motivo, desfaça a alteração...

Comment: Pq o programador antes de mim criou a classe somente para definir o tipo ai tive que fazer essa alteração seguindo um modelo mais atual

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
estatisticaNps: RetornoEstatisticaAvaliacao = {QuantidadeDetrator: 0...}
```

Só iniciar as propriedades diretamente

Comment: O jeito é fazer issso mesmo e é ate uma boa pratica:                                   estatisticaNps: RetornoEstatisticaAvaliacao = {
    PorcentagemPromotor: 0, 
    ValorNps: 0,
    QuantidadeDetrator: 0,
    QuantidadeNeutro: 0,
    QuantidadePromotor: 0, 
    PorcentagemDetrator: 0, 
    PorcentagemNeutro: 0
  };